# How to get the root style declarations on the HTML document?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I have defined some styles in the `:root` and global namespace. But when I try to access them programmatically I am getting an error:

> TypeError: Window.getComputedStyle: Argument 1 does not implement interface Element.

Here is my style rule:

```
:root {
    --my-css-variable: green; 
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
var variable = "--my-css-variable";


// all of the following error
window.getComputedStyle(window).getPropertyValue(variable);
window.getComputedStyle(window.document).getPropertyValue(variable);
window.getComputedStyle(window.document.body).getPropertyValue(variable);
```

[image]
When I select an element on the page and look in debug tools it says element is inheriting from HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--my-css-variable');
```